# Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot: where to install GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm aiming to dual-boot Win10 / Ubuntu16 with motherboard MSI x99a sli plus and hard drive Intel 600P Series 512GB M.2 SSD.

After installing windows 10 in legacy (can't detect install media when setting to UEFI in bios), installing Ubuntu results in the error
"executing 'grub-install /dev/nvme' failed"

This is not an unheard of error, and a commonly noted fix is to install grub in /dev/nvme0n1. This installs Ubuntu without problems, but upon restarting, the machine can't see the Windows option. Has this occurred to others?

Two final points to add:
- I did not install Ubuntu as UEFI (that is known to cause issues with non-UEFI OS)
- Ubuntu was a little slow to respond, although I'm not sure if it was busy installing updates

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a good solution to the grub installation, but the issue is resolved when you install using UEFI (which, as BIOS becomes obsolete, is probably the right thing to do).

The Win10 usb - from Microsoft - was not seen by the system when UEFI mode is enforced in the bios. The solution is to make your own media. Use the Windows creation tool to download the ISO (*not* to make the media), available from
https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10

To make the media, there are several tools, but Rufus is quite easy:
https://rufus.akeo.ie/
When using this tool, choose GPT as the partition scheme and FAT32 as the file system. Choose to boot using ISO image, locate the downloaded ISO file, and click start.

The resulting media is now seen by the bios, Windows is installed as UEFI (confirm in System Information), and subsequent Linux installations are uneventful.

Comment: One such guide for UEFI dual boot is http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html. I didn't have the rep to include it in my answer initially.